# Are universities always disorganized?

Tags: administration

I've been a faculty member at two universities.  Both have been very "disorganized," generally speaking. By "disorganized," I mean things like: Faculty are not formally hired until after the semester begins (due to administrative failure to sign contracts on time); courses are scheduled in rooms that are far too small for the number of students enrolled; facilities are poorly maintained (e.g., it's not uncommon for windows to break or heat to stop working in a room and not be fixed for months); HR departments don't answer email or even phone calls; pay checks are sometimes late or inaccurate, etc.

Is this a common experience at most universities, or just the ones where I've taught? Both of the places where I have been are well-known institutions -- not elite schools, but ones that are prestigious enough, and which you wouldn't expect to be poorly run.

For that matter, does this type of stuff happen in non-academic jobs, too? I have only ever worked in academia, so I don't have a lot of perspective on just how much disorganization is normal for a workplace bureaucracy. I kind of suspect academia might be a special case because it's run in large part by administrators (department heads, deans) who typically have no actual management training. But I suppose managers in the corporate world might have little idea what they are doing, too.

These are both private universities in the United States, by the way.

Comment: I commented below an answer that raised this point, but I see you’ve asked explicitly in your question too. In my experience in business / industry, **no**, [this does not happen](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/117432/are-universities-always-disorganized/117433#comment309454_117433). I mean, I’m sure it *has* happened somewhere, but it’s not normal, and people would raise a stink about it, and it would be a huge red flag for the specific company involved.

Comment: Amateurish HR I have seen in almost every university I have been (contracts being signed long after the start of employment, no regards for workplace safety and labor regulations, etc.) . Broken infrastructures much less often so. I did however visit MIT researchers that had small electric heaters in all offices because the central heating was down for several months.

Comment: I think it's not a rule. Where I did the PhD, the HR people were doing a fine job. On the other hand, we had tons of fun getting our AC fixed. Then I moved for a postdoc and the HR was understaffed. Things would usually get fixed when the faculty rebelled.

Comment: What kind of private business is the point of comparison? Restaurant kitchens in the Midwest? Sure. German car garage? Probably. Indian startup? Maybe. London Investment bank? Certainly not.

Comment: It's strategic for "courses [to be] scheduled in rooms that are far too small for the number of students enrolled," because the number of students will quickly decrease.

Comment: "Faculty are not formally hired until after the semester begins...facilities are poorly maintained...HR departments don't answer email or even phone calls; pay checks are sometimes late or inaccurate, etc." are all issues that arise due to lack of funding.

Comment: I work in a private corporation's research lab. The dishwasher in the cafeteria broke several months ago. We are still using disposables while waiting for a replacement! It can happen in the private sector too... My experience in grad school was very good though.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this](/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 2):

I worked at three different Universities in Germany and I can not confirm such a level of disorganization. Of course we are having problems because we are public entities, which means e.g. that we can not freely decide where to invest or to shift money from cost center A (e.g. personal) to cost center B (buildings), or hire as many people as we like, or pay the wages we thing are appropriate, but those problems are minor issues compared to the ones described.

It is correct that many management positions are held by amateurs (like me ;-) ), but this is manly the academic part (research, dean, ...), but our "true" administration is in the hands of professionals lead by the head of administration (in Germany "Kanzler") who usually has a management background and expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked as an adjunct in the US, and it's certainly true that I didn't get my contract until the second week or so of semester on more than one occasion.

I believe it happens because academics in the US have much more freedom (fewer institutional rules to follow) than academics in other countries or in private industry. As a result, they find it hard to get around to tasks unrelated to their key interests (usually research).

Private universities in the US seem to do this more than public ones, in my experience.

Answer (score -4):

Sure, universities are disorganized, but so are many companies. They are human organizations. The alternative is probably worse, however. Some places (both universities and companies) are rigidly hierarchical with many rules. You do what you are told to do. "My way or the highway." People, don't, in general, like to work in such places.

Good companies permit quite a lot of chaos since ideas grow out of that chaos. If you are in one of those hierarchical places it isn't a great idea to be innovative. The same is true in universities.

In most universities, much of the administration is made up of older faculty members who thought they could do a better job than they saw being done. Sometimes they are right, but not always. I was a long time into my career before I wound up at a place where I thought the administration was, at all levels, doing a good job. Unfortunately that didn't last very long as some of the good people left and were replaces with inferior models.

Another reason that universities have some chaos is that everyone there is pretty smart. Mostly, pretty smart people have ideas. Mostly they want to see those ideas implemented. Often, however, they think they are pretty smart in areas beyond their training. It can be a chaotic sort of place. It is, in a way, like a herd of horses on the move. They "organize" themselves mostly by bumping one another. Kicking is minimized, but not unheard of.

The chaos of ideas is a good thing, actually. But, *no*, disorganization isn't inevitable.

---

However there are two additional concerns, one for public and one for private universities.

Some US publicly funded universities are severely constrained by the politics of the day and the refusal of legislators to deal with rising expenses by increasing revenue (taxes), and so default to cutting services. But that is a different, external, sort of chaos over which a public university has little control.

Private universités also have, sometimes severe, financial constraints as most have little access to public monies  and depend overly on revenue obtained from student tuition. This can lead to very constrained budgets. Some take the shortfall from faculty salaries, but there is a stronger tendency to cut corners on physical plant and some services.

Education is an expensive proposition, not a profit center. Its product is a bit ephemeral.

Comment: I agree that diversity of ideas and a flexible work environment are good things. But I wouldn't interpret things like failure to maintain heating systems or process hiring contracts as the result of intellectual dynamism. I think it's just administrative dysfunction/disorganization.

Comment: I’ve never worked in academia, but I have been in industry my whole career, and I can tell you the I’ve never once experienced the symptoms OP describes (late or inaccurate paychecks, broken windows or heat, no response from HR etc), and I’ve worked in companies small and large. No, this feels like endemic to Academia. Or maybe also the public sector? I don’t know.

Comment: @DanBron, I suspect you haven't worked at new companies/startups where chaos is fairly common. Another issue, i didn't mention, of course, is that some US universities are severely constrained by the politics of the day and the refusal of legislators to deal with rising expenses by increasing revenue (taxes), and so default to cutting services. But that is a different, external, sort of chaos over which a public university has little control.

Comment: @Buffy I have worked for several startups. I’m working at one now. These kind of fundamental problems have never arisen. And neither have I heard anyone else mention any such stories from others, neither from coworkers and peers in my industry nor from friends working in others. No, there are no parallels here. Every company has problems, but they don’t suffer this kind of failure in their basic block and tackling. The paycheck issue in particular would be a huge black mark on a company and would give them a reputation which would make it hard for them to hire.

Comment: @DanBron If a company is late with paychecks, it's usually a sign that they're close to shutting down, and that their employees should look elsewhere.

Comment: @Anyon Completely agreed.

Comment: @DanBron "The paycheck issue in particular would be a huge black mark on a company and would give them a reputation which would make it hard for them to hire." -- this is highly dependent on local practice. In my experience in China, payment issues are fairly common in both companies and academia, but just hush-hushed. I will link this to my answer in this thread.

Comment: @Scientist Yes, I should have explicitly constrained my comments to “white collar business work in America”. This may happen in other countries or possibly in this country in blue collar work (I am certain it happens in under-the-table cash work). But I can only speak to the world I know.

Comment: @DanBron You've been extremely fortunate (as have I).  But I know people who have worked for _spectacularly_ disorganized/dysfunctional white-collar US companies.  Some of those companies were startups, but not all.  Most of those companies imploded, but not all.

Comment: @JeffE As I said, I am sure they exist. But it’s the exception, not the rule, and people in industry go in with expectations of working heat, timely accurate payments, and effective HR. And it’s certainly not just me: it’s everyone I worked or interacted with professionally, so it cannot be that I personally am exceptional fortunate. No, these kinds of issues are not normal, and it sounds from OP and this answer that it is so in academia. That’s the contrast I’m trying to underscore with my comments.